# Backbone JS fetch data each loop

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm trying to fetch data via Backbone JS and get each record from received JSON data. I tried many ways but always ended up with Object object, [] or some random charactors from JSON data.

```
var emp = Backbone.Model.extend({

    urlRoot:"/api/test/employees",

    initialize:function () {

    }

});

var employees = new emp();

employees.fetch({
    success: function (allEmployees) {

         $(jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(allEmployees))).each(function() {  
                  var ID = this.id;
                  var NAME = this.name;
                alert(ID+ NAME);
         });
    }
});
```

API output looks like this

```
[
    {
        "id": "10",
        "firstName": "Kathleen",
        "lastName": "Byrne",
        "title": "Sales Representative",
        "reportCount": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "firstName": "Gary",
        "lastName": "Donovan",
        "title": "Marketing",
        "reportCount": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "firstName": "Paula",
        "lastName": "Gates",
        "title": "Software Architect",
        "reportCount": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "firstName": "Amy",
        "lastName": "Jones",
        "title": "Sales Representative",
        "reportCount": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "firstName": "Paul",
        "lastName": "Jones",
        "title": "QA Manager",
        "reportCount": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "firstName": "James",
        "lastName": "King",
        "title": "President and CEO",
        "reportCount": "4"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "firstName": "Eugene",
        "lastName": "Lee",
        "title": "CFO",
        "reportCount": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "firstName": "Ray",
        "lastName": "Moore",
        "title": "VP of Sales",
        "reportCount": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "firstName": "Julie",
        "lastName": "Taylor",
        "title": "VP of Marketing",
        "reportCount": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": "12",
        "firstName": "Steven",
        "lastName": "Wells",
        "title": "Software Architect",
        "reportCount": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Williams",
        "title": "VP of Engineering",
        "reportCount": "3"
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "firstName": "Lisa",
        "lastName": "Wong",
        "title": "Marketing Manager",
        "reportCount": "0"
    }
]
```

Where am I doing wrong? How can I get record by record from received JSON data?

exactly like this

```
    {
        "id": "10",
        "firstName": "Kathleen",
        "lastName": "Byrne",
        "title": "Sales Representative",
        "reportCount": "0"
    }
```

and the next record and so on until the last one, one by one.

Comment: Do you have a collection for the model? It handles this for you.

Comment: No, I'm trying to fetch and store them in localStorage straight away one by one in above structure.

Comment: Then why are you using Backbone? Why don't you send a simple Ajax request to the server?

Comment: well, you're right but I will give it a try using backbone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No, I'm trying to fetch and store them in localStorage straight away one by one in above structure

I don't see a specific reason for using Backbone in your case, if the point of using Backbone is just getting JSON data from the server why not using jQuery `$.getJSON()` function?

```
$.getJSON('/api/test/employees', function(items) {
   $.each(items, function(_, item) {
       // doSomethingWith(item);
   });
});
```

If you want to fetch the data using Backbone, you should create a collection:

```
var EmployeesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   url: "/api/test/employees",
   model: emp
});

var Employees = new EmployeesCollection();
Employees.fetch({
    success: function(collection) {
      collection.each(function(model) {
          // doSomethingWith(model);
      });
    }
})
```

Comment: it works just like backbone would work. thanks @blacksheep :)